# THINNET 10BASE2 Network using RG-58 Coaxial Cable operating frequecy?

Tags: frequency, network, coax, bit-rate, networking

I am trying to figure out what the signal frequency of a 10BASE2 network is. Specifically the frequency of the signal being carried over coaxial cable. Data transfer is 10Mbps and the network adapters conforms to IEEE Standard 802.3-2012 for 10Base-2 networks. From reading the standard I would assume that the operating frequency is 10MHz but I know it's probably not that simple and there isn't a 1-1 corresponence between bits per second and frequency of the analog signal being carried over the cable and I don't have an o-scope.

Can any one with experience in coax networks comment on this?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie: No, the analog bandwidth of NRZ data is NOT equal to the clock frequency. It is actually approximately half that. Manchester-encoded data at 10 Mbps has an analog bandwidth of about 10 MHz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Manchester coding at 10 Mbps, a string of all-zeros or all-ones is a 10 MHz tone, and a string of alternating ones and zeros is a 5 MHz tone. So the analog bandwidth is roughly 10 MHz.